# Strange mouse wheel behavior on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, dell-optiplex

I have a Windows 7 x64 Enterprise SP1 Dell Optiplex 980 system with a Dell mouse. Under the Control Panel > Mouse, and Mouse Properties tab it says "Name: HID-compliant mouse". It's a Dell basic multimedia keyboard/mouse combo (Model #SK-8135).

Well, it's been giving me fits when I try to scroll using the wheel; when I scroll up too fast, it actually starts going down!

This is especially annoying when I hit the top of a web page -- the up scroll on the wheel starts to scroll down. What in the world is going on? Under the mouse settings, I've tried setting the Vertical Scrolling to "One screen at a time," but that's just not convenient. Can I do anything else? What's causing this bizarre behavior?

Comment: Does it happen with any other program, or just your browser? What browser?

Comment: It's in all my apps and both browsers (FF 5 and IE 9).

Comment: Same issue here. Even medium speed scrolling is really messed up and I now tend to use the laptop touch-pad instead for reading and development tasks. Really disappointing.

Comment: Ended up replacing the mouse with an older Microsoft Optical 1.1. The Dell mouse was nothing but trouble. Caused the same issue on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts are that it is either the driver, or the mouse itself, although there are a couple more things you can also try. I hate to say it though, my best guess is on the mouse, and replacing it will probably be the solution.

You should see if you can try another mouse and/or check your driver in the Device Manager to make sure that it is using Microsoft driver version 6.1.7600.16385 (I am using Windows 7 SP1).

[image]

Also in your mouse Control Panel properties, make sure the wheel setting for "The following number lines at a time" is set to one (although you can test other settings as you may find one you like better).

[image]

Lastly, check your `Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>System>Advanced system settings>Advanced>Performance` settings and test with "Smooth-scroll list boxes" checked and unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, KCotreau. Wow. That's a great and detailed answer :) I'm headed out of the office now but will check tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck @Alex. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Thanks @KCotreau. Those steps seem to have alleviated it a lot. It still does the reverse scroll a bit but not as badly as before.

Comment: I just bought the Microsoft Arc mouse and was extremely disappointed for the same reason. Following the steps above made no difference whatsoever. Reading a PDF or navigating Visual Studio is so annoying that I resort to the laptop touch-pad. Does not seem to another solution except replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mouse Wheel portion of this solution I found that setting the VERTICAL to 6 and the HORIZONTAL to 9 worked perfectly for me! Plenty of scroll down and up without the annoying bounceback it had been doing. No more scrollback for me.